# daisyui: change the color of navbar anchors when hover

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui

I am trying to change the default color of anchor elements in the navbar. It works well, but when I try to do the same for the hover state of the element, it does not work:

- Here you can see the custom link:
  [image]
- And here the link when hover: [image]

I want to keep the current background color when hover but change the text color to 'text-primary'.

My current situation is:

```
<div class="navbar-start hidden lg:flex">
        <ul class="menu menu-horizontal px-1">
            <li class="text-primary hover:text-primary"><a class="hover:text-primary">Home</a></li>
            <li class="text-primary"><a>Realisations</a></li>
            <li class="text-primary"><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

As you can see I only tried something on the home button.
Thanks for help

Comment: Better make a working example in [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/).

Comment: [It does actually work,](https://play.tailwindcss.com/tehyjY8wHd) beside I removed `hidden` on the container.

Comment: Version with Daisy added as a plugin: https://play.tailwindcss.com/h7rLjCzkSG?file=config

Comment: Thanks for ur answers. With the example from stickyuser, we can see that the solution from Kevin does not work with daisy :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [the `!important` modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier) to ensure the Tailwind class applies:

```html
<div class="navbar-start flex">
  <ul class="menu menu-horizontal px-1">
    <li class="text-primary"><a class="hover:!text-primary">Home</a></li>
    <li class="text-primary"><a>Realisations</a></li>
    <li class="text-primary"><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See this working in [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/yMbsHOvTiI).